# Elasticsearch: I have a date field and got the error: ‘Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticserach I have a date field mapping as date and got the error: 'Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default.'' on Kibana query.

The full error message is: 
"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [log_processed.time] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

The field log_processed.time is a date type.I read the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html and understand this type of error happens only with text fields.

I tried ignore_malformed: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html, but not working.

I am using the 7.4.1 version of elastic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the mapping with the "ignore_malformed" property. 
Detailed  discussion : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: I tried that, but not working.I read the documentation and  "ignore_malformed" is only to future indexes.How apply to existing indexes?

Comment: @Diogenes were you able to find the root cause of this issue? If yes, what was it and how was it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if the field is actually of type `date` in the mapping. You get the mapping of your index by (replace the `server` and `index` in the below code).

```
curl --location '{{server}}:9200/{{index}}/_mapping' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Your field should be described as something like

```
"my_date": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
 },
```

If you change the mapping, you need to index your data again.